# Winapi shell extension overriding Windows command

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, contextmenu

I developed a very basic shell extension for a little application I'm working on. I've been using it for a while now without any problem, but I just noticed that in Windows xp, in start menu -> all programs, if I right click on a folder there and choose "open" or "explore", my little application shows up instead of an explorer window. You can imagine how happy and proud I was when I saw this. I find it weird since this is the only place where it happens (so far...). I registered the shell extension under the "directory" registry key so it shows up only when a folder is right clicked.

I've found some good article on shell extensions and I made it so far with those, but I'm nowhere near my comfy zone in this winapi stuff. I did a lot of fiddling with the ids, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Here is my querycontextmenu implementation and I hope I made a dumb mistake in there that a c++ guru can spot right away. Any help will be appreciated.

```
STDMETHODIMP ShellExtension::QueryContextMenu(HMENU hMenu,  UINT indexMenu,  UINT idCmdFirst,  UINT idCmdLast, UINT uFlags){
if (CMF_DEFAULTONLY & uFlags)
{
    return MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS, 0, 0);
}

UINT uID = idCmdFirst;

if (!InsertMenu(hMenu, indexMenu, MF_SEPARATOR | MF_BYPOSITION, 0, NULL))
{
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}

HMENU hSubmenu = CreatePopupMenu();

InsertMenu (hSubmenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION, uID++, (this->isFrench ? SET_REF_TEXT : SET_REF_TEXT_EN));
InsertMenu (hSubmenu, 1, MF_BYPOSITION, uID++, (this->isFrench ? SET_COMP_TEXT : SET_COMP_TEXT_EN));

MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(mii) };
mii.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_ID | MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_DATA | MIIM_STRING;
mii.hSubMenu = hSubmenu;
mii.fType = MFT_STRING;
mii.dwTypeData = (this->isFrench ? MAIN_TEXT : MAIN_TEXT_EN);
mii.hbmpItem = IsRequirePainting() ? HBMMENU_CALLBACK : m_hMenuBmp;
mii.wID = uID++;

if (!InsertMenuItem(hMenu, indexMenu, TRUE, &mii))
{
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}

if (!InsertMenu(hMenu, indexMenu, MF_SEPARATOR | MF_BYPOSITION, 0, NULL))
{
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}

return MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS, FACILITY_NULL, uID - idCmdFirst);}
```

Thanks!

Edit:

This is the solution that worked for me... for anyone stumbling here:

```
STDMETHODIMP ShellExtension::InvokeCommand(LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO lpcmi)
{
    if (!HIWORD(lpcmi->lpVerb))
    {
        UINT idCmd = LOWORD(lpcmi->lpVerb);

        switch (idCmd)
        {
        case 0:
            doStuffForFirstCommand();
            break;
        case 1:
            doStuffForSecondCommand();
            break;
        }

        return S_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG; //this is what I forgot...
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for the code indentation, seems like I can't figure out the code tags.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/16/10305605.aspx

Comment: @Logan Capaldo Ho, my, god! Thanks a bunch! Your link led me to the following link and this is the solution I was looking for. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/6a138e65-2834-41ac-bd40-c2344e20b824#209450a5-e1d2-4f3d-bd0f-076e9d7de315

Comment: Well the real solution is to fix your InvokeCommand implementation.

Comment: @Logan Capaldo Hum I'm not too sure how to do this... I mean, in my implementation of InvokeCommand I'm only starting my application with some params. I don't really understand how it can relates to the windows explorer. Any more pointers? Do you need to see my invokecommand? Thanks

Comment: @ChG You need to check the parameter of InvokeCommand, particularly the lpVerb member.  If it doesn't match the offset of one of your menu items, you should not start your application and you should return a failure code to the OS so it can pass the request on to the proper Shell Extension.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773215(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Nick Meyer Thanks Nick, you guys were right, I didn't return a failure code after my check on lpverb... Now I do and the problem is solved. Much better than adding the "hack" registry key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll summarize the discussion above in a true answer:

In addition to being invoked by a direct user action, context menu extensions can be invoked in several other ways.  When the user selects one of the shell's built-in verbs like "Open" or "Print" when right-clicking on an item in Windows Explorer, Windows will query each of the registered shell extensions in turn to find the one that handles it.  The same thing happens if a user calls [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to invoke the verb programmatically.

This allows third party developers to add new verbs to the shell's vocabulary but also poses a problem if the shell extension doesn't handle this case.

The problem arises when the context menu handler's [`InvokeCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method doesn't check its parameter.  Here's what the documentation for [`CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has to say about the `lpVerb` member (emphasis mine):

> If the high-order word is not zero, this member is the address of a null-terminated string specifying the language-independent name of the command to carry out. This member is typically a string when a command is being activated by an application. The system provides predefined constant values for the following command strings.
>
> This is not a fixed set; new canonical verbs can be invented by context menu handlers and applications can invoke them.
>
> **If a canonical verb exists and a menu handler does not implement the canonical verb, it must return a failure code to enable the next handler to be able to handle this verb. Failing to do this will break functionality in the system including `ShellExecute`.**

Raymond Chen's blog post ["Sure, we do that: Context menu edition"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/16/10305605.aspx) describes the kind of things that can happen in this situation.  He also points the unfortunate truth that enough shell extensions exhibit this impolite behavior that the Windows team has created a [special registry key](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/6a138e65-2834-41ac-bd40-c2344e20b824#209450a5-e1d2-4f3d-bd0f-076e9d7de315) to help deal with these bugs.

Of course, if you're the developer, you should be sure to check the parameters of `InvokeCommand` and return the proper code rather than relying on the registry workaround.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I did forget to return a failure code even if I was checking the lpverb with if(!HIWORD(lpcmi->lpVerb)){do my stuff}. All is good now.